# passing query fields n rows to array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to fetch all rows to an array variable

array that i want is like this

```
$data1 = array('fields'=>array(
        array(
          'id' => 1,
          'nama_file' => "sunset.jpg",
          'judul' => "Sunset",
          'isi' => "Matahari terbenam indah sekali",           
        ),
        array(
          'id' => 2,
          'nama_file' => "water_lilies.jpg",
          'judul' => "Bunga Lilly",
          'isi' => "Bunga lilly air sangat indah",           
        ),)
```

And I've done this:

```
$q = $this->db->query('select id, nama_file, judul, isi from tfoto where dihapus ="T" ');
$data1=array('fields');
foreach($q->result() as $row) {


$data1['fields']=array('id'=>$row->id,'nama_file'=>$row->nama_file,'judul'=>$row->judul, 'isi'=>$row->isi);
}
```

test output:

```
<?php 
foreach($fields as $field){ 
echo $field['nama_file'];
.
.
.
};?>
```

and I got Message: Illegal string offset 'nama_file';'judul'; etc.

I am a newbie to MySQL/PHP, so forgive me if this is a very basic question. I tried looking all over but I could not find an answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$data1['fields']=array('id'=>$row->id,'nama_file'=>$row->nama_file,'judul'=>$row->judul, 'isi'=>$row->isi);
```

Should be:

```
$data1['fields'][] = array('id'=>$row->id,'nama_file'=>$row->nama_file,'judul'=>$row->judul, 'isi'=>$row->isi);
```

Because you have to append new arrays to `$data1` and not replacing it.